# i can't write to XML string containing path to file, c# Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i got file which contains simple XML structure, to operate on xml i use classes bulit in framework 3.5, for string not containing backslashes everything works fine, but in case strings i try to write contain backslashes final file isn't saved to disk, no exception or any kind of error at all. No matter if i write it as parrameter or as value of node, i even tried replace "\" with "\\" with no succes. What I'm doing wrong?

to create node i use following code

```
    public XmlElement ToXml(XmlDocument docXml){
        XmlElement answer = docXml.CreateElement("datafile");
        answer.SetAttribute("name", dfName);
        answer.SetAttribute("path", dfPath);
        answer.SetAttribute("user", dfUser);
        answer.SetAttribute("pass", dfPass);
        answer.SetAttribute("defalut", isDefault.ToString().ToLower());
        return answer;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Paul

Comment: Please post the full code. It seems you are creating a node with attributes, but you might not be appending it at all. See this example on how to create nodes/attributes and saving the xml file to the disc - http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/21168

Comment: how do you save your XmlDocument to disk? Can you wrap that call in a try....catch block? Does an exception happen by any chance? Something like "AccessDeniedException" or something? Are you saving the file to a network drive / share ??

Answer (score 2):

I tried this myself and I have no trouble whatsoever:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get a list of files
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\backup");

        // create new XML document
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

        // add a "root" node
        xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("ListOfFiles"));

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            xdoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(CreateXmlElement(xdoc, file));                
        }

        // save file
        xdoc.Save(@"D:\filelist.xml");
    }

    private static XmlElement CreateXmlElement(XmlDocument xmldoc, string filename)
    {
        XmlElement result = xmldoc.CreateElement("datafile");

        result.SetAttribute("name", Path.GetFileName(filename));
        result.SetAttribute("path", Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));
        result.SetAttribute("fullname", filename);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Gives me a nice, clean XML file as a result:

```
<ListOfFiles>
  <datafile name="mse-01-14.zip" path="D:\backup" fullname="D:\backup\mse-01-14.zip" />
  <datafile name="Vor_09.iso" path="D:\backup" fullname="D:\backup\Vor_09.iso" />
</ListOfFiles>
```

Not a single problem at all.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I am assuming that you are trying to put backslash for the node named "path". You can't do that.</strike>

Use [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) to put characters that should be ignored by XML parser.

EDIT: It seems "\" is not a reserved character and I was able to edit an existing XML file & put it as below.

And the browser renders it as expected.

```
<Employees xmlns="http://Employees">
  <Employee id="12615" title="Architect">
    <!--This is a comment-->
    <Name>
      <First>Nancy</First>
      <Middle>J.</Middle>
      <Last>Davolio</Last>
    </Name>
    <Street>507 - 20th Ave. E. Apt. 2A</Street>
    <City>Seattle</City>
    <Zip>98122</Zip>
    <Country>
      <Name test="\abc">U.S.A.\\\\</Name>
    </Country>
    <Office>5/7682</Office>
    <Phone>(206) 555-9857</Phone>
    <Photo>Photo.jpg</Photo>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

What is the content of the variable that has backslash in it?

Comment: I removed my answer and voted up this one.  It seems to be more related to the actual question.  In addition, it seems to be correct.